# select price by weight and classification

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am trying to set a "price" of a product  by its classification and weight.

For example, I have 3 types of classifications GOOD, OK, and BAD.

Each classification has a price range according to its weight.  For example, classification (GOOD < 100 = $price1, > 100 = $price2, ) , (ok < 100 = $price1, >100 = $price2, ) and (bad <100 = $price1, >100 = $price2, ).

If the product is classified as GOOD and the weight of the product is < 100 its $price1 is 25 , but if the product is  classified as GOOD but wight > its $price2 is 20.

My database looks like this:

```
table name: classification 
three columns: name, price1, price2
(price1 is for <100)
(price2 is for >100)
```

This is what I have so far :

```
  product: <input id="product" name="product">
  weight:  <input id="weight"  name="weight>

  <label for="classifications"">classifications</label>         

  <div class="selector-classifications">
      <select class="form-control" id="classifications" name="classifications" required> 
      </select>
  </div>                           

  price: <input  id="price" name="price">
```

The selector for classifications gets all the name of the classifications:

```
$fetch = "SELECT * FROM classification"; 
$result = mysqli_query($con, $fetch) or die("error");
echo '<option value="0">choose option...</option>';
while (($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) != NULL) 
{
    echo '<option value="'.$fila["name"].'">'.$fila["name"].'</option>';
}
```

my problem is that I am trying to take the value of weight and classification to show its price in the price input without reloading the page.

Comment: where is your ajax call?

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "../ajax/autocomplete/classifications.php",
                    success: function(response)
                    {
                        $('.selector-classifications select').html(response).fadeIn();
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>